# activerecord PostgreSQLAdapter override sql_for_insert, query, execute and update_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to update all sql statements for the queries generated for sql_for_insert, query, execute and update_sql for postgres. I'm using rails 3.2.17. Main aim is to change the column names to lower case. I tried to define a class "class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter" in initializers, methods are called over there, but I can't call super as my class isn't extended from any other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an alternate solution to just update the column names at one single location. I made a module and included it in Arel:Attributes:Attribute, this module converts the column names into lower case. This code is still under testing for me and not into production. But this seemed to have solved my problem.

```
module ArelAttributeWrapper
  def self.included base
    @actualname = nil
    base.class_eval do
      def initialize(*args)
        super(*args)
        @actualname = args[1]
      end
      def name=(value)
        @actualname = value.downcase
      end

      def name
        @actualname.downcase
      end
    end
  end
end

Arel::Attributes::Attribute.send(:include, ArelAttributeWrapper)
```